# OpenStreetMap roads vs lines

Tags: openstreetmap, road

I imported OpenStreetMap data of Karlsruhe to PostGis using osm2pgsql. This creates 4 table, one names planet_osm_roads. Sadly this table does only contains major streets. Smaller streets can be found within planet_osm_line, along with a lot of other stuff such as railways, bicycle tracks...

Is this an error of OSM or on purpose? Do you know any data set containing all streets which can be accessed by car?

Comment: Read http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql/schema. You have all data in osm_lines but you must learn the tags and how to filter by them.

Comment: Thanks, did not know that page. This helps